# Concavity of a nested logarithm including any positive and concave function

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $x>0$ and $f(x)\neq\pm\infty$ be a continuous function and twice differentiable,concave  on $(0,\infty)$ then define :

$$g(x)=\ln(\ln(\cdots\ln(f(x)+1)+1)+1)\cdots)+1)$$

Where we compose $n$ times the function $h(x)=\ln(x+1)$ with itself .

then :

$$g''(x)\leq 0$$

Base case $n=2$:

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\ln(1 + \ln(f(x) + 1))) = \frac{((f(x) + 1) f''(x) (\ln(f(x) + 1) + 1) - f'(x)^2 (\ln(f(x) + 1) + 2))}{((f(x) + 1)^2 (\ln(f(x) + 1) + 1)^2)}$$

It's straightforward to see that all is negative so we are done !

The general is similar but the second derivative becomes monstruous .

Question :

How to show it in the general case in a short way ?

Comment: Lemma: if $f,g$ are concave and $f$ is increasing then $f\circ g$ is concave.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) > 0$ or at least $f(x) > -1$? Otherwise the expression may be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that the natural log of a positive concave function is concave. Let $h(x)$ be positive concave on $(0,\infty)$. Then $$ ( \ln h(x) )’’=\frac{hh’’ -(h’)^2}{h^2} \le 0 $$ as $hh’$ and $-(h’)^2$ are both $\le 0$.